# WPF DataTemplate Tutorials

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datatemplate

I am stuck in how to use DataTamplete in WPF, someone knows some tutorial or has a colection of turorials that teach how to use it??

I'm using MVVM Pattern, so if you know a tutorial in mvvm examples it will be better. ;)

Tks!

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: I see @GarryVass... But i'm searching for the most simplest way to use DataTamplete and how far can i go with it. i know how MVVM can be polemic lol

Comment: The best way is to take a working example of something that's transparent and to see how it fits together.  The .NET DriveInfo and/or FileInfo classes make excellent examples...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Googling "wpf datatempalte tutorial" give following links. i would recommend #2

1. [Data Templating Overview - MSDN - Microsoft](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521%28v=vs.110%29.aspx&ei=ezI0U_yqBvL74QSYqYGwDg&usg=AFQjCNG4-xlUR79Bu3mnu1czvsf0TdwZ-g&sig2=3RyFIjqwt7tBLyk036DtWQ&bvm=bv.63808443,d.bGE)
2. [WPF Tutorial | Data Templates](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDkQFjAB&url=http://wpftutorial.net/DataTemplates.html&ei=ezI0U_yqBvL74QSYqYGwDg&usg=AFQjCNFy-NDsNc8fdCyVmMVgA6ZRQaSxyQ&sig2=PgMz7_Bs3sJt8XQ2HI0-rg&bvm=bv.63808443,d.bGE)
3. [A Guided Tour of WPF – Part 4 (Data templates and triggers...](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEIQFjAC&url=http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18303/A-Guided-Tour-of-WPF-Part-Data-templates-and-tri&ei=ezI0U_yqBvL74QSYqYGwDg&usg=AFQjCNGzI5YoPk1pQAvvIESHwiODQFTPeg&sig2=gzhe2wYwfbcA0jodPqvNMw&bvm=bv.63808443,d.bGE)

Comment: Nice Examples! I'm trying now [Load multiple UserControls on WPF window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367115/load-multiple-usercontrols-on-wpf-window)

Comment: Sad how this question was the third Google result for me.

Answer (score 1):

MSDN explains it well [MSDN Data Templating Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Things to watch out for are that your itemsource is set correctly and that the properties you are binding to are public.

Comment: Ok, i'm reading this. your link is with problem, i'm using this  [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Sorry not sure what happened there its fixed now.